# CSS rest of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a page with one navigationbar and one div (wrapper). Now i want that the div (wrapper) fill the rest of the page with a background-color and put the text in the middle (vertical).

Here is my Code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: rgb(25, 81, 118);
    text-align: justify;
}

.text{
    width: 70%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: white;
}

ul{
    font-size: 0px;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
}

a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: rgb(25, 81, 118);
    transition: all 0.5s;
    font-size: 22px;
}

a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(25, 81, 118);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="wrapper">
        <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on your css do:

```
body {
    background-color: white;
}
```

this will fill all the background with the color you want.

```
.wrapper {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

this will center the div with the class wrapper

Comment: I have one more little problem... the align vertival wont work. Here is my body: `<body>
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </body>` and here the css: `body{
    background-color: rgb(0, 70, 85);
}

text{
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    display: block;
}` Maybe you have an idea for me.

Comment: you're missing a "." before text

Comment: Yeha. I found this mistake too, but it still wont work.

Comment: are you sure the css file is being called?

Comment: HTML <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="text">Filler</div>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: CSS *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(0, 70, 85);
}

.text{
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
}

Comment: try putting margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; inside the body css

Comment: inspect the element and see which css is running there

Comment: Its running on the body the css: body{
    background-color: rgb(0, 70, 85);
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
}

Comment: and on the wrapper is it also running the margins?

Comment: no i deleted the margin-bottom: auto; margin-top: auto; in the wrapper

Comment: try instead of margin-bottom: auto; and margin-top: auto;

margin-bottom: 50%; margin-top: 50%;

Answer (score 3):

Add display `table` and `height: 100%` to element with class `.wrapper` and display `table-cell` and `veritcal-align: middle` to element with class `.text`:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
    display: table;/*add display table*/
    height: 100%;/*add height 100%*/
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: rgb(25, 81, 118);
    text-align: justify;
}

.text{
    width: 70%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: table-cell;/*add display table-cell*/
    vertical-align: middle;/*add vertical align middle*/
}

nav{
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: white;
}

ul{
    font-size: 0px;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
}

a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: rgb(25, 81, 118);
    transition: all 0.5s;
    font-size: 22px;
}

a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(25, 81, 118);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="wrapper">
        <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the  tag's background color to the navy, and since the background color for your nav bar is already set to white, it will override the blue background for that div.

```
body {background-color: rgb(25, 81, 118);}
```

It is advised that anything you have set in your wrapper div will have that background color, so if you continue to add more content, the navy background will continue to fill the page.  Considering there is only one paragraph, the wrapper ends where the content ends leaving a large white space when viewing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Flex Layout** to solve this problem. Put the vendor prefixes by yourself.

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;           /*   <-------- Added this */
    flex-direction: column;  /*   <-------- Added this */
}

.wrapper{
    flex: 1;                 /*   <-------- Added this */
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: rgb(25, 81, 118);
    text-align: justify;
}

.text{
    width: 70%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: white;
}

ul{
    font-size: 0px;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
}

a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: rgb(25, 81, 118);
    transition: all 0.5s;
    font-size: 22px;
}

a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(25, 81, 118);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="wrapper">
        <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```